# Kubeconfig /config

Tags: docker, kubernetes

After execute k8sviz.sh script and try to run docker container do not found config dir.

Docker trys to retrieve /root/.kube/config, config file is not loaded to dockern container

Docker image mkimuram/k8sviz

Execute ./k8sviz.sh